# DATE_ICAL and strtotime in PHP

Tags: php, icalendar

I have dates in my database in local British times (i.e. GMT in the winter and BST in the summer). I want to convert them to DATE_ICAL for displaying into iCalendar format. I have tried both the following.

```
date(DATE_ICAL, strtotime($row['FixtureDate']);
date(DATE_ICAL, strtotime($row['FixtureDate'].' UTC');
```

My first date for example is 12:45 BST. If I use the first statement I get 20140809T124500Z and the second I get 20140809T134500Z. Neither shows the right date in Google.

The second is obviously wrong because my time is not a UTC time, I think I need to convert my time to a UTC time as that's what DATE_ICAL wants? But how do I do that?

My server is British. I only care about British times and British users.

Comment: `DATE_ICAL` is not a PHP constant, where does it come from? date can also not change timezones for you. The Z is probably simply wrong and hardcoded.

Comment: Sorry I should have put that in: define('DATE_ICAL', 'Ymd\THis\Z');

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally figured it out, I needed to use GMDATE not DATE with ICAL format

```
define('DATE_ICAL', 'Ymd\THis\Z');
GMDATE(DATE_ICAL, strtotime($row['FixtureDate']));
```